# WCF Rest Service - Return either an object or a list/array of objects from same method?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, wcf-rest

I have a WCF REST service which is being called by another application/service (which I don't have control over).  This other service expects to call a single service method from my service and potentially get back either a single JSON object or an array of said objects.  I haven't had an issue with the service returning either of these, but can't figure out how (or if it is possible) to have either the object or array of object to be returned from the same service method.  Here's an example of the code:

**Return single JSON object:**

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
  [DataMember]
  public string ItemId { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public int number { get; set; }
}


[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   UriTemplate = "items")]
public Item GetItems(RequestObject requestItems)
{
  Item newItem = SqlDataAccess.GetStandaloneItem(requestItems);
  return newItem;

  //Return format is:
  //{"ItemId" :"ABCDEFG","number" :90}
}
```

**Return array of the objects:**

```
[DataContract]
public class ItemList
{
   [DataMember]   
   public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   UriTemplate = "items")]
public ItemList GetItems(RequestObject requestItems)
{
  ItemList newItemList = SqlDataAccess.GetItems(requestItems);
  return newItemList;

  //Return format is:

  //{"items": [
  //     {"ItemId" :"ABCDEFG","number" :30},
  //     {"ItemId" :"HIJKLMN","number" :49},...]
  //}
}
```

The idea would be to combine these two so that either type (Item or ItemList) can be returned.  Ideally the app/service calling this would be able to handle an array with only one object, which they have agreed to support, but their change won't be made before we need to go live.

I have yet to find a way to do this - the only thing that looked like it might help is the ServiceKnownTypeAttribute... am I on the right track?

I appreciate any assistance/advice.

Comment: What is wrong with returning a list of 1 item?

Comment: @shahkalpesh - there should not be a problem, but the application calling the method doesn't like the list with one item.  They've agreed that they should accept this, but they won't update their code to accept it until after my project needs to be finished.

Comment: How about a linked list of items? i.e. return an item with `Next` property in case there are multiple items, `null` otherwise.

Comment: @shahkalpesh - another good suggestion - thank you.  However, unless I misunderstand, this still requires a change on the application/service end for which I have no control over.  I'm looking for a way to return either of the formats above (commented out in the examples) from 1 endpoint without requiring any change on the application/service calling this method.